# ImportError: No module named gym_gazebo

Tags: ros, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, gazebo-simu

I am trying to install gym_gazebo on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS system according to https://github.com/erlerobot/gym-gazebo

Everything is getting installed correctly, however, while trying to run python
`circuit2_turtlebot_lidar_qlearn.py`

, I get error as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "circuit2_turtlebot_lidar_qlearn.py", line 4, in \<module\>
import gym_gazebo
ImportError: No module named gym_gazebo
```

anyone can help me please

some advice that can help me solve that